# Creating virtual thumbnail of image with PHP

Tags: php

I want to display the thumbnail of image while displaying time,but dont want to save the image.

I have tried some `notorious ;)` script but its not working :(. Please have look and let me know do you have any idea

```
<?php
    function print_thumb($src, $desired_width = 100){
        /* read the source image */
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
        $width = imagesx($source_image);
        $height = imagesy($source_image);

        /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
        $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

        /* create a new, "virtual" image */
        $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

        /* copy source image at a resized size */
        imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);


        // Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

        // Output the image
        imagejpeg($virtual_image);

    }
?>

<img src="<?php print_thumb("s1.jpg"); ?>" />
```

I saved this file as `thumbs.php` (single file)   while accessing it via localhost it displaying like

`<img src="http://localhost/test/thumbs.php">`

Its working fine if I write both in separate file.

like `file.html` with

`<img src="thumb.php?img=s1.jpg" />`

and

thumb.php

```
<?php
    function print_thumb($src, $desired_width = 100){
        /* read the source image */
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
        $width = imagesx($source_image);
        $height = imagesy($source_image);

        /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
        $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

        /* create a new, "virtual" image */
        $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

        /* copy source image at a resized size */
        imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);


        // Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

        // Output the image
        imagejpeg($virtual_image);

    }

    print_thumb($_REQUEST['img']);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 separate scripts.

1 to output the image `image/jpg` and one to output the HTML. You appear to be trying to render the image directly to the `src` attribute.

HTML Page:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="http://localhost/test/thumbs.php?img=s1.jpg">
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP Page:

```
<?php
    function print_thumb($src, $desired_width = 100){
        // your function as is
    }

    // you should probably sanitize this input
    print_thumb($_REQUEST['img']);
?>
```

Comment: Wooooow, thats cool. but why its not accepting in single file .

Comment: The `src` attribute is not the actual image data. It tells the browser to make another request to the server to fetch the image, *then* it reads the image data.

Comment: Coool buddy, reallly gr8 answer\

Answer (score 0):

Try using "TimThumb" ([CLICK HERE](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/)), it makes things like this very easy indeed.

Comment: I know there is many libraries, but i want to do it my own way ;)

Answer (score 0):

If `<img src="<?php print_thumb("s1.jpg"); ?>" />` is part of thumbs.php as in your shown code, then you have to remove it. I also suggest removing `?>` from thumbs.php

Answer (score 0):

### Inside 'thumb.php'

```
<?php

  function print_thumb($src, $desired_width = 100){

    if( !file_exists($src) )
      return false;

    /* read the source image */
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
    $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);


    // Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    // Output the image
    imagejpeg($virtual_image);

    return true;

  }

  if( isset( $_GET['file'] ) && !empty( $_GET['file'] ) ){

    if( !print_thumb( $_GET['file'] ) ){

      echo 'Failed to create thumb for "'.$_GET['file'].'"';

    }else{

      // The Thumb would have been returned

    }

  }else{

    echo 'No File specified';

  }
?>
```

### Inside any page displaying the thumbnails

```
<img src="thumb.php?file=s1.jpg" />
```

The problem you have with your existing code is that you are putting the wrong code in the wrong file. The *thumb.php* file is meant to do nothing but look at the parameters it is being sent (the file it is meant to turn into a thumbnail) and return the image.

So putting the `<img....` markup at the end of that file is where your problem is.

Instead, you have to look at where you are trying to make the images appear. And you have to pass that image filename into the markup, so the *thumbs.php* file know what you want it to thumbnail and return.

As another respondant noted, there are libraries which will do this for you alot easier than writing it up yourself.